# how get username from message (Telethon)?

Tags: python, telethon

I undersood how to get messages from Telegram-chat. But I can't get usernames.

```
messages = history.messages
for message in messages:
   print(message.message)
   print(message.username) #error ????????????????????
```

I want to get usernames from messages
I wanted get usernames.
What method i need to use?
Help me please.

Comment: Have you checkes the documentation? https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message (Looks like you want `from_id` or `post_author`?)

Comment: Always include the error message. See [ask].